# Override vlookup formula excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2 sheet workbook. An order sheet that populates from a data sheet using the vlookup formula. Once the work is complete the order sheet is printed and cleared. However, the user occasionally needs to change a cell value in the order sheet (protected), but keep the original value in the source, unaltered. Basically manual override a cell. 
Is there is a way or a code to allow manual override of a cell value but retain the formula for future use?

Comment: If the user changes the value in the Order Sheet it will override the vlookup formula. If the user is just 'printing' the order sheet at this point, and not saving the work that has been done, then the source data and formula should remain the same for the next time to book is opened. If the user has the ability to save however, it will overwrite the formula but the source data should remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this without VBA by using a helper cell.

Rather than having the user overwrite the cell with the formula, they could enter the required temporary value in a helper cell somewhere off to the side of the printed area.

The `VLOOKUP` formula could be wrapped in an `IF` statement which displays the helper cell value if present, otherwise it uses the `VLOOKUP` formula and displays the result.

`=IF(COUNTBLANK(H1)=0,H1,VLOOKUP(…))`

Assumed helper cell is `H1`, obvs. change to suit.

The user can then change/delete the value in the helper cell as required without affecting the formula in the output cell.

The VBA route would be to use the `Worksheet_Change` event and update the cell formula if the target cell was empty

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim CellRng As Range

    Set CellRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'cell with formula, change to suit

    If Not Intersect(Target, CellRng) Is Nothing Then

        If CellRng.Value = vbNullString Then _
        CellRng.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(…)" 'change formula to suit

    End If

End Sub
```

This would allow the user to overwrite the formula in that cell with a different value, but would reset the formula when the user deletes or clears contents of that cell.

If you can accommodate the helper cell I think the non-VBA route is more intuitive for the user; having a cell which doesn't remain empty after you delete the contents could be confusing.

Comment: Thanks thatandyward. The helper cell worked perfectly.